# Ignoring results from a list which is a lookuplist

Tags: search, search-results

Lets say I have a list which will be hidden with the following columns:

```
clientcode, clientname, country, clientowner
001, google, usa, john smith.
```

Then I have a document library called Client Documents,this document library has a lookup column to the list Clients.

```
document name, document title, language, client lookup
analysis.docx , analysis project x, english,  001
```

Now I want the search to behave like this:
if the user types google.

I dont want to show the results of the hidden list, however the document should come up because of the lookup.  The same applies if I try to search by JohnSmith.

Questions are:

1. How to exclude the hidden list from search results.
2. If I exclude it, I will still be available to search for keywords in documents related?
3. What should I be aware of during the setup of the list/document library/search service application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure but I think you should include the other fields in the hidden list as dependent columns when setting up the lookup column. That way when you search on any of those extra columns the documents from the library will show up in search results. Also, you can perform following steps for not including content from a list in search results:

> Show or hide content from lists or libraries in search results As a
>   site owner, you can decide whether items in lists and libraries on
>   your site are included in search results. By default every list and
>   library is set to include all items in search results.
>
> NOTE    To change this setting, you must have the Manage Lists
>   permission level. The Designer and “Site Name” Owner groups contain
>   this permission level. When you do not have Manage Lists permissions,
>   the menus described in this procedure are not available.
>
> Navigate to the site that contains the list or library that you want
>   to change. Locate and click the list or library you want to customize.
>   Click Site Actions, and then click Site Settings. Under Site
>   Administration, click Site Libraries and lists. Click an item from the
>   list, for example, Customize “Shared Documents.” On the List Settings
>   page, under General Settings, click Advanced settings. In the Search
>   section, under Allow items from this document library to appear in
>   search results, select Yes to include all of the items in the list or
>   library in search result or No to exclude all items from search
>   results.